# How do i use findAll method with a class in Doctrine?

Tags: class, doctrine

I am a little bit confused with Doctrine class. I created a class and its base class in Doctrine. The class's name is User.

so..I created an object of class User.

```
$oUser = new User();
```

when I try to use the `findAll` method, it does not work. I found the following code on the doctrine documentation:

```
Doctrine_Core::getTable('User')->findAll();
```

I don't understand why i need to call `getTable` to use the `findAll` method when I have User class.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AFAIK User object represents a single row in a table.if you need all the users you need to ask the table.

Answer (score 13):

For Doctrine 2, you need to get the repository:

```
$AllUsers = EM()->getRepository('Users')->findAll();
```